# Codeigniter search with pagination

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i have implemented search with pagination.
Controller function `public function search()
    {

```
    if($_POST)
    {
        $search_name=$this->input->post('search_name');
        $config['base_url'] = 'search';
        $config['total_rows'] = 15;//$this->registration_model->record_count();
        $config['per_page'] = 4;
        $config["uri_segment"] = 3;
        $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
        $data['result']=$this->institute_model->search_result($config["per_page"],$page,$search_name);
        $data['links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
        $this->load->view('institute/search',$data);
    }
}`
```

And Model function code is

```
public function search_result($limit,$start,$search_name)
{
    $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
    $this->db->select('user_id');
    $this->db->where('category',1);
    $this->db->like('first_name',$search_name);
    $query = $this->db->get('registration');
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {

        foreach ($query->result() as $row) {

            $data[] = $row;

        }

        return $data;

    }

    return false;




}
```

I am searching from registration table having userid and fname etc. searching is based on username. It works for me but when i click page 2 on pagination it goes to `http://localhost/mypro/index.php/institute/search/2` and goes blank.

Comment: Good. Now, what have done so far? Or you just want a ready-made script?

Comment: Follow this tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_livesearch.asp If you come across any problems, do some research first, if you still can't find a solution, ask for help here, including in your question what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use plugin [Jquery Pagintation](https://github.com/neotohin/CodeIgniter-Ajax-pagination-Library)

Add jquery before loading view.

```
//Define model function with limit
public function modelFunction($limit=0)
    {
        $this->db->select("....col_name....");
            //....................
            //.........
        $this->db->limit(10,$limit)->order_by('id', 'desc');
        return $this->db->get()->result_array();

    }



//Define controller function with limit
function controllerFunction($limit = 0)
    {
        $config['base_url'] = path_to_controllerFunction
        $config['total_rows'] = call_to_total_count_function;
        $config['per_page'] = 10;
        $data["total"] = call_to_total_count_function;
        $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
        $data["per_page"] = 10;
        $config['full_tag_open'] = "<div class = 'pagination'>";
        $config['full_tag_close'] = "</div>";
        //$config['additional_param']  = 'serialize_form()';
        $config['div'] = '#div_to_load_result'; /* Here #content is the CSS selector for target DIV */
        //$config['js_rebind'] = "alert('it works !!'); "; /* if you want to bind extra js code */
        $this->load->library('table');
        $this->jquery_pagination->initialize($config);
        $html  =  $this->jquery_pagination->create_links();
        $html .= '<br>';
        //$this->table->function = 'htmlspecialchars';
        //$this->table->set_heading('Delivery','image','time','delivery','old');
        $html .= $this->table->generate($this->modelname->modelFunction( $limit ));

        echo $html;
    }


        // first time loading result in controller
function index()
    {
        $config['base_url'] = controllerFunction
        $config['total_rows'] = total_number_of_result;
        $config['per_page'] = 10;
        $data["total"] = total_number_of_result
        $data["per_page"] = 10;
        $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
        $config['full_tag_open'] = "<div class = 'pagination'>";
        $config['full_tag_close'] = "</div>";
        //$config['additional_param']  = 'serialize_form()';
        $config['div'] = '#div_to_load_result'; /* Here #content is the CSS selector for target DIV */
        //$config['js_rebind'] = "alert('it works !!'); "; /* if you want to bind extra js code */
        $this->load->library('table');
        $this->jquery_pagination->initialize($config);
        $data['html'] =  $this->jquery_pagination->create_links().'<br>'.$this->table->generate($this->modelname->modelFunction());

        $this->theme->view(path_of_view, $data);
    }
// now in view  add following line 
<div id="div_to_load_result"><?php echo $html; ?></div>
```